# How to get only updated checkbox status in listview android

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a listview with a checkbox in a dialog. Now I need to get only the updated checkbox item from the dialog's 'ok click'. For example if the user checks only one checkbox in the row I need to get only that status, but if the user checks and unchecks the checkbox I don't want that status. I tried using a hash table to get and remove statuses when checked, but on listview scroll the checkbox event gets executed and hash table filled with the wrong values.

```
public class SelectGroupAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {
    Activity activity;
    ArrayList<SelectGroupItems> data = new ArrayList<>();
Hashtable<Integer,Boolean> status;
    public SelectGroupAdaptor(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void add(SelectGroupItems selectGroupItems) {
        this.data.add(selectGroupItems);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        status=new Hashtable<>();

    }

    public ArrayList<SelectGroupItems> getCheckedData () {
        return data;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView;
        CheckBox checkBox;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.layout_select_group_row, null);

        }
        textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        textView.setTypeface(Util.setCustomFont(activity));
        checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        textView.setText(data.get(position).getGroupName());
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                         boolean isChecked) {
                    data.get(position).setChecked(isChecked);
                if(status!=null)
                {
                    if(status.get(position)!=null)
                    {
                        status.remove(position);
                    }else
                    {
                        status.put(position,isChecked);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        checkBox.setChecked((data.get(position).isChecked()));

        return convertView;
    }
    public  Hashtable<Integer,Boolean> getStatus()
    {
        return status;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me

Comment: so what is the position value? And you already have a data list that stores the item checked status, I think the status Hashtable is not really needed. If you need to know what is checked, you can loop the data list to find out.

Comment: Please improve your question by using punctuation. Your question is hardly readable.

Comment: There is some issues in your code.you are not using holder. So it will change while scrolling the listView.

Comment: i need the output like this when i call getStatus() the hashtable with the position of item and boolean status of the checkbox  only which is modified

Answer (score 1):

You don't need HashMap, a simple item holder class with a status property would help you. See your modified code:

Edit: If I understood you correctly, you want to get the `SelectGroupItems` object when its check status changed? If so see edited code below:

```
public class SelectGroupAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {

    Activity activity;
    ArrayList<SelectGroupItemHolder> data = new ArrayList<SelectGroupItemHolder>();

    OnItemCheckStatusChangedListener onItemCheckStatusChangedListener;

    // a item holder class, not a view holder
    private static class SelectGroupItemHolder {
        SelectGroupItems selectGroupItems;
        boolean status;
    }

    public interface OnItemCheckStatusChangedListener {
        public void onItemCheckStatusChanged(SelectGroupItems selectGroupItems, boolean checkStatus, int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemCheckStatusChangedListener(OnItemCheckStatusChangedListener onItemCheckStatusChangedListener) {
        this.onItemCheckStatusChangedListener = onItemCheckStatusChangedListener;
    }

    public SelectGroupAdaptor(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void add(SelectGroupItems selectGroupItems) {
        SelectGroupItemHolder selectGroupItemHolder = new SelectGroupItemHolder();
        selectGroupItemHolder.selectGroupItems = selectGroupItems;
        this.data.add(selectGroupItemHolder);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public ArrayList<SelectGroupItems> getCheckedData() {
        ArrayList<SelectGroupItems> checkedItemList = new ArrayList<SelectGroupItems>();
        for (SelectGroupItemHolder selectGroupItemHolder : data) {
            if (selectGroupItemHolder.status) {
                checkedItemList.add(selectGroupItemHolder.selectGroupItems);
            }
        }
        return checkedItemList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView;
        CheckBox checkBox;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.layout_select_group_row, null);

        }
        textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        textView.setTypeface(Util.setCustomFont(activity));
        checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        textView.setText(data.get(position).selectGroupItems.getGroupName());
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                data.get(position).status = isChecked;

                if(onItemCheckStatusChangedListener != null) {
                    onItemCheckStatusChangedListener.onItemCheckStatusChanged(data.get(position).selectGroupItems, data.get(position).status, position);
                }
            }
        });
        checkBox.setChecked((data.get(position).status));

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Set the check status change listener of your selectGroupAdapter instance. ie:

```
    selectGroupAdaptor.setOnItemCheckStatusChangedListener(new SelectGroupAdaptor.OnItemCheckStatusChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemCheckStatusChanged(SelectGroupItems selectGroupItems, boolean checkStatus, int position) {
            // handle check status change
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response but this will give me only the checkedItemList but i need like this if i have 5 checkbox in that first 2 is true and rest 3 is false initially(checkBox.setChecked((data.get(position).status));) and the user uncheck the second one i need that one only(position(2) and the status(false) )